# Mocking Files during a ChefSpec run

Tags: rspec, chef-infra, chefspec

I created a Chef resource which 'extends' the deploy resource of chef. The basic idea is to check for the existence of a file `deploy/crontab` similar to mechanisms `deploy/after_restart.rb` in the source to be deployed, and create cronjobs out of it.

While this mechanism works as it should be (see https://github.com/fh/easybib-cookbooks/blob/t/cron-tests/easybib/providers/deploy.rb#L11-L14), I am struggling with a ChefSpec based test for it. I am currently trying to create mocks using `FakeFS` - but when I mock the Filesystem before the Chef run, the run fails because no cookbooks are found, since they do not exist in the mocked filesystem. If I dont, the mocked file `deploy/crontab` is obviously not found, so the provider doesnt do anything. My current approach is to trigger `FakeFS.activate!` directly before `runner.converge(described_recipe)` in the chef_run.

I would love to hear some recommendations how to do a proper test here: Is there maybe some possiblity to enable the FakeFS only directly before the deploy-resource-run, or to mock the Filesystem only partially?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem stubbing the File system classes. The way that I have been solving this problem is as follows.

```
::File.stub(:exists?).with(anything).and_call_original
::File.stub(:exists?).with('/tmp/deploy/crontab').and_return true

open_file = double('file')
allow(open_file).to receive(:each_line).and_yield('line1').and_yield('line2')

::File.stub(:open).and_call_original
::File.stub(:open).with('/tmp/deploy/crontab').and_return open_file
```

Comment: Yes, this works- but my problem here is that I have to mock the content of the file as well, since I have to read/parse the content: https://github.com/fh/easybib-cookbooks/blob/t/cron-tests/easybib/providers/crontab.rb#L22

Comment: Similarly you can do the following.

    ::File.stub(:open).with(anything).and_call_original
    ::File.stub(:open).with('/tmp/deploy/crontab').and_return 'content'

Comment: No, since this is a string, and does (according to the error) not supply the `each_line` method :)

Comment: You can mock the open file object that is returned by the File.open?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It does mostly work ;) I uploaded a shrunk down version of my current test setup here: https://github.com/fh/chefspec-debugging

The problem is that it apparently never reaches https://github.com/fh/chefspec-debugging/blob/master/easybib/providers/crontab.rb#L17 - the mocked return value of the each_line call seems to be wrong, since it does not execute the loop. Not sure why, maybe you have an idea.

Comment: After some more tweaking: it should not use `and_return`, but `and_yield`, with multiple yields if multiple lines are needed. I updated your response, the tests works now :)

Comment: Great, glad to hear it!

Comment: @punkle Thanks for your post, I think it's better in general to use `::File.stub(:open).and_call_original` instead of `::File.stub(:open).with(anything).and_call_original`. Indeed, it will catch any usages of `open`. The old way was failing for me in some cases because it was called sometimes with one argument and another time with two.

Comment: @Matt that makes total sense. I have updated the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Since punkle's solutions is syntactically deprecated and there are some parts missing, I'll try to give a new solution:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'cookbook::recipe' do

  let(:chef_run) { ChefSpec::SoloRunner.converge(described_recipe) }


  file_content = <<-EOF
...here goes your
multiline
file content
EOF

  describe 'describe what your recipe should do' do

    before(:each) do
      allow(File).to receive(:exists?).with(anything).and_call_original
      allow(File).to receive(:exists?).with('/path/to/file/that/should/exist').and_return true
      allow(File).to receive(:read).with(anything).and_call_original
      allow(File).to receive(:read).with('/path/to/file/that/should/exist').and_return file_content
    end

    it 'describe what should happen with the file...' do
      expect(chef_run).to #...
    end
  end

end
```